# Two different outcomes (-1 and 1) for Legendre symbol?

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

I'm trying to solve the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{97}{131}\right)$. With my calculation I end up with 1.

```
(97/131) ={97=1(4)} (131/97) 
= (34/97) ={97=1(4)} (97/34) 
= (29/34) ={29=1(4)} (34/29) 
= (5/29) ={5=1(4)} (29/5) = (4/5) = (2^2/5) = 1
```

In the solution, it continues at (34/97) like so:

```
(34/97) = (2/97)(17/97) 
= (17/97) ={97=1(4)} (97/17) 
= (12/17) = (3/17)(2^2/17) = (3/17) 
={17=1(4)} (17/3) = (2/3) ={3=3(8)} -1
```

So there the solution is -1. I checked both calculations multiple times and they seem fine to me. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $34=54^2\pmod{131}$ so $97$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $131$.  I think quadratic reciprocity is when both are odd primes.

Comment: @MatthewTowers My bad, should've been 2 x 17. Doesn't make a difference for the calculation though.

Comment: @Empy2 Ahh I think that's the problem here. 34 isn't an odd prime so I wasn't allowed to apply QRL there. Thanks. If you want you can post an answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$34=54^2\pmod{131}$ so $97$ is not a quadratic residue of $131$.
I think quadratic reciprocity only works if both are odd primes.

Comment: Just wondering, why 34 = 54^2 (mod 131) and not just 34 = 17 * 2 for example?

Comment: 34 and 97 are mutually exclusive as quadratic residues of 131 because $131=3\pmod4$, and I kept adding 131 to 34 until I got a square.

Comment: Okay, but why? I'm trying to understand why you go this route when it's pretty easy to tell that 34 is not odd nor a prime.

Comment: In general, adding 131 many times would be a much slower method than Quadratic Reciprocity, but in this case I was trying to find which answer was correct. 
  '97 is not a quadratic residue' seemed harder to show than '34 is'